# does incremented column makes the b-tree index on the column unbalanced?

Tags: database, performance, oracle, indexing, b-tree

I have been thinking about two questions. Couldn't find any resources on the internet about this. How do dbms handle it ? Or do they ? Especially Oracle.

Before the questions, here is an example: Say I have a master table "MASTER" and slave table "SLAVE".
 Master table has an "ID" column which is the primary key and index is created by Oracle.Slave table has the foreign key "MASTER_ID" which refers to master table and "SLAVE_NO". These two together is the primary key of slave table, which is again indexed.

```
 **MASTER**  |  **SLAVE**
     (P) ID <------> (P)(F) MASTER_ID 
                     (P) SLAVE_NO
```

Now the questions;

1- If MASTER_ID is an autoincremented column, and no record is ever deleted, doesn't this get the table's index unbalanced ? Does Oracle rebuilds indexes periodically ? As far as i know Oracle only balances index branches at build time. Does Oracle re-builds indexes Automatically ever ? Say if the level goes up to some high levels ?

2- Assuming Oracle does not rebuild automatically, apart from scheduling a job that rebuilds index periodically, would it be wiser to order SLAVE table's primary key columns reverse ? I mean instead of "MASTER_ID", "SLAVE_NO" ordering it as "SLAVE_NO", "MASTER_ID"i, would it help the slave table's b-tree index be more balanced ? (Well each master table might not have exact number of slave records, but still, seems better than reverse order)

Anyone know anything about that ? Or opinions ?

Comment: What do you mean by "skewed"?

Comment: I mean the b-tree index gets unbalanced?

Comment: I seriously doubt that Oracle, after years and years of development of their flagship product, would allow this situation to occur - but I could be wrong.  Sounds like a perfect opportunity to engage in a little bit of detectoring and research.  We'll look forward to your paper in Communications of the ACM.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> If `MASTER_ID` is an autoincremented column, and no record is ever deleted, doesn't this get the table's index unbalanced ?

`Oracle`'s indexes are never "unbalanced": every leaf in the index is at the same depth as any other leaf.

No page split introduces a new level by itself: a leaf page does not become a parent for new pages like it would be on a non-self-balancing tree.

Instead, a sibling for the split page is made and the new record (plus possibly some of the records from the old page) go to the new page. A pointer to the new page is added to the parent.

If the parent page is out of space too (can't accept the pointer to the newly created leaf page), it gets split as well, and so on.

These splits can propagate up to the root page, whose split is the only thing which increases the index depth (and does it for all pages at once).

Index pages are additionally organized into double-linked lists, each list on its own level. This would be impossible if the tree were unbalanced.

If `master_id` is auto-incremented this means that all splits occur at the end (such called `90/10` splits) which makes the most dense index possible.

> Would it be wiser to order `SLAVE` table's primary key columns reverse?

No, it would not, for the reasons above.

If you join `slave` to `master` often, you may consider creating a `CLUSTER` of the two tables, indexed by `master_id`. This means that the records from both tables, sharing the same `master_id`, go to the same or nearby data pages which makes a join between them very fast.

When the engine found a record from `master`, with an index or whatever, this also means it already has found the records from `slave` to be joined with that `master`. And vice versa, locating a `slave` also means locating its `master`.

Comment: Well, i remember my previous and first job,couple of months ago,dba did some Oracle training sessions,told if the data is not that equally distributed,then the data would make one side of the tree grow more in depth.Then we should rebuild index,or see what kind of data is going to be in that column:D

Apparently, better not believe everything blindly:) Popped into my mind today,so about all those operational systems having a field incrementally growing :) 
Did some reading on Asktom.Mentioning no need to rebuild periodically.Tho did not say Oracle was managing it in this way.Thx @Quassnoi

Comment: These kinds of data structures are really early 70's or even late 60's, published, studied and taught on every CS class with all drawbacks, benefits and so on. It does not take an Einstein to implement it, and almost every database on Earth uses some kind of auto-increment id. This is the kind of thing which you need to implement first in an alpha-pre-release of any database, and Oracle is really old.

Comment: @brhneser: he probably expressed himself incorrectly, meaning that uneven distribution leaves too much almost-emtpy pages, like Justin Cave explained below.

Answer (score 4):

The b-tree index on `MASTER_ID` will remain balanced for most useful definitions of "balanced".  In particular, the distance between the root block and any child block will always be the same and the amount of data in any branch will be at least roughly euqal to the amount of data in any other sibling branch.

As you insert data into an index on a sequence-generated column, Oracle will perform 90-10 block splits on the leaves when the amount of data in any particular level increases.  If, for example, you have a leaf block that can hold 10 rows, when it is full and you want to add an 11th row, Oracle creates a new block, leaves the first 9 entries in the first block, puts 2 entries in the new block, and updates the parent block with the address of the new block.  If the parent block needs to split because it is holding addresses for too many children, a similar process takes place.  That leaves the indexes relatively balanced throughout their life.  Richard Foote (the expert on Oracle indexes) has an excellent blog on [When Does an Oracle Index Increase in Height](http://richardfoote.wordpress.com/2008/04/03/so-when-does-an-oracle-b-tree-index-increase-in-height-almost-grown/) that goes into much more detail about how this works.

The only case that you potentially have to worry about an index becoming skewed is when you regularly delete most but not all blocks from the left-hand side of the index.  If, for example, you decide to delete 90% of the data from the left-hand side of the index leaving one row in every leaf node pointing to data, your index can become unbalanced in the sense that some paths lead to vastly more data than other paths.  Oracle doesn't reclaim index leaf nodes until they are completely empty so you can end up with the left-hand side of the index using a lot more space than is really necessary.  This doesn't really affect the performance of the system much-- it is more of a space utilization issue-- but it can be fixed by coalescing the index after you've purged the data (or structuring your purges so that you don't leave lots of sparse blocks).

Comment: @Justin, so if one has an option to insert mostly incrementing value vs randomly sorted, what would be more efficient for the database *in general*? Can that be given a definitive answer? From what you write I think the randomly sorting would be preferable. I would appreciate if you can answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15669788/optimizing-generated-string-for-storing-into-a-database

Comment: @akostadinov - My answer here is heavily dependent on the internal operations of Oracle in particular.  Your question is talking about three different databases none of which are Oracle.  Realistically, the answer will depend on the database (and since you're talking about MySQL probably the storage engine you choose).  I'm not an expert in the internals of any of those databases, though, so I'm not sure I can help you.